# Are same name functions in different classes supported in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can nodejs have two functions in different classes with the same name ?
If not then why not ? otherwise there is something wrong in the code.

Following is the example;

```
var admins = require('./routes/admins');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

Both singleton classes

```
var users = function users(){ 

     this.foo = foo = function(bar){ ...
     }
}

users.getInstance = getInstance = function(){
    if(this.instance == null){
        this.instance = new users();
    }
    return this.instance;
}

module.exports = users.getInstance();
```

The **admin** class is also similar, both the classes have the same function names as well.

Now when **foo** is called it gets called of **user** class no matter what.
If i change the *require* order the **foo** of admin class is called.

Comment: Please reword this question. You are not clear about what you are asking, though the information you provided indicates the beginning of a question worth understanding and answering as you are experiencing an issue with the order of items being loaded and accounting for runtime processing of two same named functions.

Comment: I have edited the question but I do believe the question was pretty straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As literally written in your question, I don't see a reason why this would happen.  However, you are leaking into global scope, and that's how you might end up with duplicates.

```
users.getInstance = getInstance = function(){ ...
```

First, notice that the middle `getInstance` isn't scoped with `var`, so it gets assigned to the global scope.  While this doesn't cause immediate problems, you're still polluting global scope, which is bad.

The real issue appears if you just do:

```
module.exports = getInstance();
```

Whether or not you've scoped `getInstance` with `var`, you're calling it in the global context, which means that inside the function, `this == global`.  This means that the first time the function runs, it is basically doing:

```
global.instance = new users();
```

...and when your second file runs, it sees there's already a `global.instance` and just returns it.

Consider using `'use strict';` so these kinds of errors are caught for you.

---

Finally -- why are you doing all these `getInstance` gymnastics?  They are entirely unnecessary.  Your users file should just look like:

```
exports.foo = function(bar) {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the function name are same and the code is executed in sequential order, the function inside the second class overrides the first.

So the function will be called from whichever file is in second place.

Comment: Different classes, same name functions. Does nodejs mixes them up ?